# Does login with Instagram use session ID still exist?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, instagram

Currently, I'm trying to learn Puppeteer on Node.js to access an Instagram account page without using a username and password for login. I believe that if I continuously attempt to log in with my username and password, Instagram may block my account. I've been searching for alternative methods to set the existing session ID. I've tried it, but it only works for a few seconds until the popup warning prompts me to log in again.

[image]

Here is my code :

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const _ = require('lodash');

const testRun = async () => {
    const launchOptions = {
        headless: false,
        slowmo: 50,
    };
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchOptions);
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
        'Cookie' : 'sessionid=<my existing session ID>',
      });

    await page.goto("https://www.instagram.com/p/CxUR12qLPl5/", {
        waitUntil: "networkidle2",
        timeout: 0,
    });
 
};

testRun();
```

Is there any way to avoid logging in with a username and password? Please Advice.

Comment: you'll have to fake _everything_ the other browser uses, including user agent string, etags, etc. Otherwise you're using "clearly a different user agent" and Instagram wisely asks you to reauthenticate. Because there is no reason to assume it's you, it could be anyone who got hold of your session id and is now trying to impersonate you.

Comment: i've been tried to add 'User-Agent', 'Accept', 'Accept-Encoding', 'Sec-Ch-Ua', 'Sec-Ch-Ua-Full-Version-List', 'Viewport-Width', 'Sec-Ch-Prefers-Color-Scheme', 'Dpr', 'Cache-Control', 'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile', 'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform', 'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform-Version', 'Sec-Fetch-Dest', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode', 'Sec-Fetch-Site', 'Sec-Fetch-User', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests'. but non of this work.

Comment: Don't "try", look things up. Check the full request headers set in your browser's dev tools' network tab, and use identical values (just copy the URL request as Fetch instruction and take it from there - that won't copy everything, but its a start and then you fill in the blanks).

Comment: You also need to actively preserve cookies from one puppeteer run to the next if you want the prior login to still be active.